# I am not able to use flutter as im getting an error with the dart sdk, only it has been working for weeks until today

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently having this issue and can't find any solutions that work. Yesterday It was running fine and this afternoon when I wanted to code I received this message in the terminal.

flutter run... Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine <<<<<<< HEAD 07c1eed46b9d9b58df78566e9b8b2e42e80d3380
92ae191c17a53144bf4d62f3863c110be08e3fd3

8f89f6505b941329a864fef1527243a72800bf4d... curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Failed to retrieve the Dart SDK from: https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/flutter/<<<<<<< HEAD 07c1eed46b9d9b58df78566e9b8b2e42e80d3380
92ae191c17a53144bf4d62f3863c110be08e3fd3

8f89f6505b941329a864fef1527243a72800bf4d/dart-sdk-linux-x64.zip If you're located in China, please see this page: https://flutter.dev/community/china

I am not using a VPN, am not from china, and as I said this was running yesterday. I have tried reinstalling the flutter package, tried redirecting to redoing the path in Linux, also tried to just clone the github/flutter repo but nothing. Please help

Comment: Those are some sketchy links in the post.
I wouldn't click on them.

Comment: those links were copied straight from the terminal, have you any idea what the issue is?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found that there was an issue with a file in
flutter/bin/internal called engine.version that had the same text as the "head" issue as mentioned in the error code. I have replaced the file with the one from the flutter GitHub repo and the error has gone. will close the issue.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/bin/internal/engine.version

Answer (score 5):

Replace the `/flutter/bin/internal/engine.version`  with the one from this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/bin/internal/engine.version
and then run

```
flutter doctor
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I was getting that error too. Fixed by fixing the line-endings using the `dos2unix` utility:

Install dos2unix with `sudo apt install dos2unix`

Then run this in terminal:

```
dos2unix ~/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/internal/engine.version
```

Comment: That actually worked for me. Instead of using dos2unix I opened the engine.version file in VSCode and changed the line ending to "LF" (being on MacOS).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, tried everything I found on the internet but nothing worked... Finally, went to the folder where my flutter installation was, deleted the flutter folder, downloaded the flutter sdk again and named the unzipped folder exactly as the previous one: flutter.

This worked for me, so if all else fails, you can try this one.