# I am not able to use flutter. It just stopped randomly working fine like 5 mins ago due to this sdk error

Tags: flutter

```
Building flutter tool...
Error: Error when reading '../../../flutter/packages/flutter_tools/.packages': No such file or directory
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'flutter_tools' in 'package:flutter_tools/executable.dart'.
../../../flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/flutter_tools.dart:7:8: Error: Not found: 'package:flutter_tools/executable.dart'
import 'package:flutter_tools/executable.dart' as executable;
       ^
../../../flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/flutter_tools.dart:10:14: Error: Method not found: 'main'.
  executable.main(args);
             ^^^^
```

I had the issue in this post before and i followed its solution : [I am not able to use flutter as im getting an error with the dart sdk, only it has been working for weeks until today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65600214/i-am-not-able-to-use-flutter-as-im-getting-an-error-with-the-dart-sdk-only-it-h)    then i ran into the error above.. anything i can do..

Comment: Sorry about that. Have you tried flutter doctor? And maybe reinstall Flutter if it gets tough.

Comment: yes i reintsalled flutter now and its working just fine

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled flutter linux version and it works just fine.

Comment: Great accept your answer as solution to help those who will come to the question in future

Comment: I can accept my answer min after 2 days